# Use the ajax output in a callback function inside a plugin (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I want to make the output of an AJAX call accessible in a callback function in my plugin. The plugin is for an contact form so it send the data with AJAX, but i need to see the ouput in a log/alert. I already have an callback function called 'after'.

// the part that I am using now

```
$.ajax({
   success: function(data){
      if(typeof options.after == 'function'){
         options.after.call(this);
      } 
   }
});
```

// the options and how I want to use it

```
$.fn.dform.options = {
   option1: 'lorem',
   option2: 'lorem',
   option3: 'lorem',
   after: function(e){
      console.log(e)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply send it (`data`) as a parameter when you invoke `after()`:

```
if(typeof options.after == 'function'){
     options.after.call(this, data);
}
```

**Edit** [Here's MDN's documentation of `call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).